# ImportError on debugger with Eclipse and Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, importerror

I have a python project within Eclipse with the pydev plugin. Although I can run the scripts just fine through the "run as" dialog, or the "run configurations" profiles, it fails on an import when using the debugger (launching through "Debug configurations" with the same configuration that I use from "Run configurations").

The pythonpath should be alright, because the run command is working just fine. It is only the debug run that is facing the import error.

Things I have tried so far, by following advices on similar topics:

- deleting the project and recreating (even rebooting the whole system)
- removing the interpreter and adding it again so that the pythonpath
  is recalculated
- making sure that the project folders are imported in
  the pythonpath
- the scripts work alright also when running from the
  windows command line

How can I make the debugger work with these scripts, when it's already resolving the import alright with the regular run?

Versions:

- Windows XP Pro SP3
- Eclipse SDK 4.2.1
- Pydev 2.7.1

Thanks!

Comment: I had similar issues with the debugger, make sure you don't have any python files names like the source files of the pydev plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Damjan, but that's not the case.

Comment: Update: actually Damjan Dimitrioski was right. I was not aware that in the latest PyDev version there is a path which includes "third_party", which is used in some module for my code. Downgrading the pydev version from 2.7.1 to 2.4.0 solves the problem as the path name is then "ThirdParty" and does not conflict with my "third_party".